# About hermiticity implying non-nilpotency for infinite dimensional vector space(Corrected)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nilpotence

Suppose $A$ is a non-trivial linear operator acting upon infinity dimensional vector space. Say given $A^2$=0 and provide that $A$ is hermitian. Is this sufficient to conclude $A$ is non nilpotent? I could not come up with counter example so far.

Comment: A counter example is $A=0$, which is nilpotent, hermitian and satisfies $A^2=0$. It acts on any vector space.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it has to be non-trivial.

Comment: Notice that $\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\langle x, A^2x\rangle=\langle x, 0\rangle=0$. Thus, for every $x\in V$, $Ax=0$.